# Pandas cumulative sum of partial elements with groupby

Tags: python, pandas

Apologies if this question has already been asked, but thank you in advance for your help.

In this "unpivoted" dataset, there are **Orders** composed of several **Lots**. Each **Lot** has a given **Point** value, as below:

```
CustID     Date         OrderNum   LotNum   PtsPerLot
A123       1/1/2015     1234       A        2            
A123       1/1/2015     1234       B        10
A123       1/1/2015     5678       A        7
```

My objective is to create a `CUMULATIVE_POINTS_PER_YEAR` column representing the cumulative sum of `POINTS_PER_ORDER`, which is itself a sum of `PtsPerLot`, at each `Lot` level. So, for a given lot, `CumPtsPerYear` would show the cumulative total of all `POINTS_PER_ORDER` for an account in a given year.

```
CustID     Date         OrderNum   LotNum   PtsPerLot    *PtsPerOrder*    *CumPtsPerYear*
A123       1/1/2015     1234       A        2            12              12
A123       1/1/2015     1234       B        10           12              12
A123       1/1/2015     5678       A        7            7               19
```

Any ideas? I've tried `groupby.cumsum` on `PtsPerLot` and another `groupby.cumsum` on `PtsPerOrder`, but it isn't producing what I need.

Comment: How is CumPtsPerYear the cumulative sum of PtsPerOrder?

Comment: Order #1234, between the two lots, sums to 12 points.

Comment: Right, but cumulative sum of PtsPerOrder would be 12, 24, 31...

Comment: I agree -- that's one of the things I'm struggling with. I need `PtsPerOrder` that represents the `.sum()` of the `ordernumber` field in each lot row. in that case, it'd be fine for `CumPtsPerYear` to be the sum only of the first Lot in that order. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, calculate `PtsPerOrder`. Use `transform` to *broadcast* along the actual index of your dataframe the result of the calculation in each group:

```
df['PtsPerOrder'] = df.groupby('OrderNum')['PtsPerLot'].transform(sum)
```

Then take the first element of that new column in each group:

```
df['CumPtsPerYear'] = df.groupby('OrderNum')['PtsPerOrder'].head(1)

df
Out[27]: 
  CustID      Date  OrderNum LotNum  PtsPerLot  PtsPerOrder  CumPtsPerYear
0   A123  1/1/2015      1234      A          2           12           12.0
1   A123  1/1/2015      1234      B         10           12            NaN
2   A123  1/1/2015      5678      A          7            7            7.0
```

End the calculation by doing the cumulative sum you are searching for. It will skip the NA values. You complete your dataframe with a forward fill:

```
df['CumPtsPerYear'].cumsum().ffill()

0    12.0
1    12.0
2    19.0
```

Comment: *this* makes sense.

Comment: No, that was meant to be for @user791411, actually. I couldn't make sense of specification, but when I see it in `pandas` it makes sense now. I was getting confused about lots and ordernums. Did not realize this was you! I did not think your other answer didn't make sense, it was just a suggesting for elaboration.

Comment: @Boud because I have to groupby both the `CustID` and the `Year` to get cumulative points per year, Pandas is now spitting a `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis` error on the `head(1)` row. Any thoughts?

Comment: This `df['CumPtsPerYear'] = df.groupby(['CustID', 'Date', 'OrderNum'])['PtsPerOrder'].head(1)` will work the same so I'm not sure to understand your issue

Comment: I'm not sure either -- Pandas is throwing that error when I ran the code. As an FYI I don't have a `rowID` column or any other index in this dataframe (it's composed of several CSV files merged together) -- not sure if that's the reason?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to use a [transformation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation):

```
df['*PtsPerOrder*'] = df.groupby('OrderNum')['PtsPerLot'].transform(sum)
```

Then in order to create the other one, I didn't find another way that to find the max of each group, do a cumsum on that, and merge that back in:

```
weird_cumsum = df.groupby('OrderNum')['*PtsPerOrder*'].max().cumsum().to_frame()
weird_cumsum.columns = ['*CumPtsPerYear*']
weird_cumsum

          *CumPtsPerYear*
OrderNum                 
1234                   12
5678                   19

df.merge(weird_cumsum, left_on='OrderNum', right_index=True, how='left')
```

Result is as expected:

```
  CustID       Date  OrderNum LotNum  PtsPerLot  *PtsPerOrder*  *CumPtsPerYear* 
0   A123 2015-01-01      1234      A          2             12             12  
1   A123 2015-01-01      1234      B         10             12             12   
2   A123 2015-01-01      5678      A          7              7             19
```

Answer (score 0):

To get to the first part of your question, `PtsPerOrder`, you need a *transformation*. `sum` is an aggregation. So use `.transform`:

```
In [10]: df
Out[10]:
            Date  OrderNum LotNum  PtsPerLot
CustID
A123    1/1/2015      1234      A          2
A123    1/1/2015      1234      B         10
A123    1/1/2015      5678      A          7

In [11]: df.groupby('OrderNum')['PtsPerLot'].transform('sum')
Out[11]:
CustID
A123    12
A123    12
A123     7
dtype: int64
```

And use that to create a new column...

```
In [13]: df['PtsPerOrder'] = df.groupby('OrderNum')['PtsPerLot'].transform('sum')

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
            Date  OrderNum LotNum  PtsPerLot  PtsPerOrder
CustID
A123    1/1/2015      1234      A          2           12
A123    1/1/2015      1234      B         10           12
A123    1/1/2015      5678      A          7            7
```

I'm still not grokking your specification for CumPtsPerYear ...

Comment: Thanks for your help! In that instance, because there are 12 total points in that order (as in the column) and 7 total points in the subsequent order, `CumPtsPerYear` would be 12, 19.